# Iframe from Adsense (250x250) auto-resizes Iframe for Youtube on same page to 250x250

Tags: iframe, youtube, cross-domain, adsense

The same page ( www.goo.gl/xLAhN )  has a youtube video embedded in size 640x390 in an iframe using the following code: (3 variations of youtube embed code were tried all with same results)

```
`<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/GxTl1Ykbuww?enablejsapi=1&origin=origin-domain.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>`
```

The same page has one Adsense banner embedded in 250x250 in an iframe using the following code:

```
`<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
/* test */
google_ad_slot = "xxxxxxx";
google_ad_width = 250;
google_ad_height = 250;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>`
```

100% of the time the youtube video displays at 250x250. Looking at the view source, the Youtube iframe now has a style element attached to it with 250x250 directive.

```
`<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/GxTl1Ykbuww?enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=origin-domain.com" frameborder="0" style="width: 250px; height: 250px;"></iframe>`
```

If the adsense code is removed , youtube video loads in correct size.

Please help, after 5 days I think this is either CORS related, but there is nothing online about this problem. Somehow adsense is allowed to overcome cross domain restrictions and inject the youtube iframe with the size of its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had to do with jquery that was part of the theme that beautified iframes

```
var win = jQuery(window),
 iframes = jQuery('iframe:not(.slideshow iframe):not( iframe.no_resize)',container),
 adjust_iframes = function() {
    iframes.each(function() {
        var iframe = jQuery(this),frame_parent_w = iframe.parent().width(),proportions = 16/9;
        if(this.width && this.height) {
            proportions = Math.round(this.width / this.height * 1000) / 1000;
            iframes.css({
                width:frame_parent_w,height: frame_parent_w / proportions});
        }
    });
};
adjust_iframes();
win.smartresize(adjust_iframes);
```

After I added :not(inside iframe) to the second line (since Adsense always has their iframe wrapped in inside tags, everything rendered as expected with the above code ignoring the Adsense iframe settings.